# Meaning of "eine Debatte, die keine sein dürfte"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, modal-verb

From the [Frankfurter Allgemeine](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/debatten/social-freezing-der-fetisch-mit-den-frischzellen-13252138.html):

> Apples und Facebooks Angebot, ihren Mitarbeiterinnen künftig eine Frist-Freikarte für die Reproduktion zu spendieren, hat eine Debatte ausgelöst, **die keine sein dürfte**. Es ist nämlich, aus medizinischer Sicht, ein ganz und gar unmoralisches Angebot.

What does "die keine sein dürfte" mean here? Does "keine" refer to "Debatte"?

I think it should mean roughly "a debate that should not have been (started)", but I don't understand why "dürfte" is used here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base phrase

> etw. darf nicht sein
>   *(often in the form of)* Das darf doch nicht sein!

*literally* means that something is not allowed to be/must not be (following some set of rules), but is almost exclusively used for things that **are** happening, inferring the disfavor of the speaker: "I can't believe this is happening [since it's not allowed], right?"

> etw. dürfte nicht sein

on the other hand, expresses that something is happening **and** that it is apparently being tolerated (implicitly allowing it), which - following the writers opinion - **shouldn't** be. Similarly to how you need this subjunctive in English, you need the *dürfte* in the text (Konjunktiv II / Irrealis).

A literal translation would look like this:

> A debate that shouldn't be one.

I'm not sure that can be said in English, so here are some other tries:

> A debate, that shouldn't have become one in the first place.
>   ...initiated a debate, where there shouldn't be one.
>   ...now there's a debate, where there shouldn't have been one in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in assuming that it means *a debate that should not have been*

A literal translation would be

> A debate that should not have been allowed

Mind you, this is not in the sense of "should have been forbidden".